# Magento 2 Undefined offset during migration

Tags: database, magento2.3, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I'm getting next error during migrate:data

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php on line 455

```
            $destinationRecord->setValue(
            'entity_type_id',
            $this->mapEntityTypeIdsDestOldNew[$destinationRecord->getValue('entity_type_id')]
        );
```

I've tried to truncate all eav tables, but this error dont go away. How can i solve it?

Comment: getting same error